# Rails method in helper doesn't work in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method in a helper file that is pretty simple. It takes an object (`tool`) that has_many `services`. Each `service` has a `:completed` date. I want this method to use the built in associations to check each `service`. If the `service.name` contains the string "annual" AND the `service.completed.year == DateTime.now.year`, then the method should return true, else it should return false. Here is my method in the tools_helper.rb file:

```
def annual_service?
  self.services.each do |service|
    if (service.name =~ /annual/) && (service.completed.year == DateTime.now.year)
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

Too.rb model:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :repairs
  has_many :services
  has_many :expended_parts, through: :services
  has_many :service_types, through: :services
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :repairs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services

  validates :serial, :uniqueness => true
  validates :serial,  :presence => true
end
```

Service.rb model:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :replace_parts
  belongs_to :tool
  belongs_to :service_type
  has_many :expended_parts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parts, through: :expended_parts

  after_create :withdraw_parts

  default_scope order('due_date DESC')
end
```

I can do this on the Rails console:

```
t = Tool.find(16)
t.services.each do |service|
 if (service.name =~ /annual/) && (service.completed.year == DateTime.now.year)  
   puts "true"
 end  
end

returns =>  true
```

But if I do:

```
t.annual_service?

returns => false
```

I'm not getting an `unknown method` error, and if I do:

```
t.respond_to? :annual_service

returns => true
```

I'm missing something simple. but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods in helper module can't take effect in controller and model file automatically. In your view you can use helper method directly.

Maybe you could include the helper module to "Tool" class and try again. Just like:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Your_Helper_Module # ToolsHelper?
  ............................

end
```

Comment: Ah! I keep forgetting this fact. I am using this in the view. Is there a way to load it in the console to be able to test it?

Comment: Could my solution work? Include your module into model class.

Comment: Yes, I accepted it once I tested it in the view. Thanks!